# What are the foundational papers in computational phonology?

Tags: phonology, computational-linguistics, reference-request

I'm working on a paper on the history of computational phonology.

As I understand it, Chomsky & Halle's SPE acted as a catalyst for research in the field, namely by laying the foundations for two-level models and POS taggers. Fraser and Bobrow designed the first phonological rule-testing system the same year (1968).

The introduction of automata in phonological rule systems by Kaplan and Kay, years later, seems to be a turning point. Prince and Smolensky's Optimality Theory in the mid 90's as well.

**What are other important papers / innovations in computational phonology?** I am still doing research, but your input is most welcome. This is my list so far:

- Bobrow, D. G., & Fraser, J. B. (1968). A phonological rule tester. *Communications of the ACM*, *11*, 766-772.
- Chomsky, N., & Halle, M. (1968). *The sound pattern of English*. New York, NY: Harper & Row.
- Kaplan, R. N., & Kay, M. (1994). Regular models of phonological rule systems. *Computational Linguistics*, *20*(3), 331-378.
- Koskenniemi, K. (1984). *Two-level morphology: A general computational model for word-form recognition and production*. Helsinki: University of Helsinki.
- Prince, A., & Smolensky, P. (1993). *Optimality Theory: Constraint interaction in generative grammar* (Tech Report CU-CS-533-91). Boulder, CO: University of Colorado Boulder.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure if this paper is considered landmark enough, but it is a good survey and starting point (in particular the claim that all phonological patterns are (sub-)regular is stressed): http://udel.edu/~heinz/papers/Heinz-2011-CPF.pdf

Comment: I see that you include a paper on computational morphology. Albright and Hayes [1] wrote a seminal paper on the English past tense which presents a phonological rule learner (Minimal Generalization Learner downloadable at [link](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/people/hayes/learning/#Software))

[1] (2003) Adam Albright and Bruce Hayes. Rules vs. analogy in English past tenses:  a computational/experimental Study.  Cognition 90:119-161.

Comment: @user3898238 Thank you. I don't know that Heinz's paper is influential, but as you said, it should lead me to others that are.

Comment: @coffeemachine Yes, I included it because Koskenniemi introduced a formalism that is used in phonological rule systems. [Bird (1994)](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/J94-3000) also stated that what we call finite-state morphology should often be be referred to as morphophonology. Thank you for sharing Albright and Hayes's paper.